# Можно ли реализовать интеграцию с сервисом (используя его АПИ) с помощью HttpClient?

Tags: c#, https, httpclient, гост

HttpClient от System.Net.Http.

Характеристики HTTPS соединения (предоставленные сервисом):

- Алгоритм шифрования: ГОСТ 28147-89;
- Алгоритм выработки и проверки электронной подписи: ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012
- Алгоритм хэширования: ГОСТ Р 34.11-2012;

Нужно ли как-то дополнительно настраивать HttpClient?
Подойдет ли он вообще для данной задачи?

Comment: Можно, только `HttpClient` это инвокер. На самом деле вся магия происходит внутри реализации `HttpClientHandler`, а именно `SocketsHttpHandler` - вот с ним и разбирайтесь.